# Cheapest countries to visit from Dubai

Tags: international-travel

I have recently shifted to dubai and i am looking for countries where i can travel on budget. Places that are nearer and can be covered over a weekend. I am considering going out in Feb.

Answer (score 0):

**Kish Island** in Iran, a short flight away, is the traditional destination for quick visa runs from the UAE.  Unlike the rest of Iran, it's a designated tourism zone that all nationals can visit without a visa.  Beware that Iranian laws apply, so women must cover up and don't expect alcohol or wild nightlife.

https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kish_Island